# How to retrieve google appengine entities using their numerical id?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to retrieve an entity from google appengine using their numerical IDs and if so how?
I tried using:

key = Key.from_path("ModelName", numericalId)
m = ModelName.get(key)

but the key generated wasnt correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id

Comment: how to do it? I dont understand. Please explain more

Answer (score 0):

[Getting an Entity Using a Key](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Getting_an_Entity_Using_a_Key)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to do

key = Key.from_path( Application_ModelName, numeric_id )

wasn't clear till i looked at the dict() of an entity

Answer (score 0):

Other answers refer to the old DB API. New applications will by default use the NDB datastore, which has a slightly different API. You can still do Model.get_by_id(id, parent) to retrieve an entity by id, but the NDB also supports options to specify the app and namespace. See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id) for details.